# How to find $f: \Bbb N \to \Bbb R$, $f(m+n)=f(m) +f(n) +a$, for all $m,n\in\Bbb N$, $a\in \Bbb R$

Tags: analysis

$f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$  with
\begin{equation*}
     f(m+n)=f(m) +f(n) +a     
\end{equation*}
for all $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$.
$f(2)=10$ and $f(20)=118$. 
Is $f$ unique? 
Find $f$ and $a$.

Comment: Hint: $f(n+1) = f(n)+ f(1) + a$.

Comment: What have you done to solve it?

Comment: I tried to begin with f(20+2)=f(20)+f(2)+a=118+20+a=138+a but then I didn't know what to do next. I have to use induction at one point, right?

Comment: @NikoB. It looks like a huge step towards solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(2n) = f(2n-2) + f(2) + a = f(2n-4) + 2f(2) + 2a = .. = f(2) + (n-1)(f (2) + a)$

Therefore $f(20) = f(2) + 9(f(2) + a)$ and we get $a$ from here.

From $f(2) = f(1) + f(1) + a$ we get $f(1)$.

Should be easy from here.

Answer (score 0):

Using the given property and the given value of $f(2)$, go in steps of $2$ to get an expression for $f(20)$. What I mean is: find an expression for $f(4)=f(2+2)$, then an expression for $f(6)=f(4+2)$, then an expression for $f(6)=f(4+2)$, and so on, until you get to $f(20)=f(18+2)$. (Or, instead of actually doing that step by step, you can observe a pattern and prove it by induction.) Comparing that last expression with the given value of $f(20)$ will allow you to find $a$. Then setting up $10=f(2)=f(1+1)=f(1)+f(1)+a$ and using the already found value of $a$ will let you find $f(1)$. So the function will be unique, and based on $f(1)$ and $a$ you can find a formula for it and prove it by induction.

Comment: Doesn't it has to be $f(4)=f(2)+f(2)+a$? Or do you mean, I can define $f$ myself?

Comment: @NikoB.: Yes, after you apply the given equality: $f(4)=f(2+2)=f(2)+f(2)+a$.

Comment: Of course, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

$f(n) = f(n-1) + f(1) + a = $

$f(n-2) + 2f(1) + 2a = .... = $

$f(n-k) + kf(1) + ka =.. f(2) + (n-2)f(1) + (n-2)a =$

$ f(1) + (n-1)f(1) + (n-1)a = n*f(1) + (n-1)a$

We could formally (rather than informally) prove $f(n) = n*f(1) + (n-1)a$ by induction, if we wanted to.

So $f(2) = 2f(1) + a = 10$

and $f(20) = 20f(1) + 19a = 118$

Solve for $f(1)$ and for $a$.  These are two linear independent equations so there will be a unique solution that I am too lazy to figure out. (It  will be a pair of rational numbers for what it is worth).

then you will have $f(n) = mn + b$ where $m = f(1)+a$ and $b = -a$.  This will be a unique linear function.  (FWIW the range will, of course, not be all of $\mathbb R$ but a very small subset of $\mathbb Q$.  But that isn't relevent.)

Comment: a = 10 - 2f(1); 20f(1) - 19(10 - 2f(1)) = 58f(1) - 190 = 118; 58f(1) = 308; f(1) = 308/58 = 154/29.  a = 10-308/29 = - 18/29.  So f(n) = (136n + 18)/29.  Unless I made an arithmetic error which I'm 87% sure I have.

Comment: or 20f(1) + 10a = 100 so 9a = 18 so a = 2.  so 2f(1) + 2 = 10 so f(1) = 4.  Check 20*4 + 19*2 = 80 + 38 = 118.  check.  So f(n) = 6n - 2.  And obviously I made an error in my first comment.  I always do when I do arithmetic.

Comment: Oh... *plus* 19(10-2(f1))....  -18f(1) +190 = 118; 18f(1) = 72; f(1) = 4; a = 10 - 2*4 = 2.  So f(n) = 6n -2.

Answer (score 0):

Making $m=1$ we get $f(n+1)=f(n)+f(1)+a$ wich define a arithmetic sequence with rate $f(1)+a$. Using the last relation we get:
$$f(n)=f(1)+(n-1)(f(1)+a)$$
Using $f(2)=10$ and $f(20)=118$:
$$f(2)=10=f(1)+f(1)+a=2f(1)+a$$
$$f(20)=118=f(1)+19(f(1)+a)=20f(1)+19a$$
So we get $f(1)=4$ and $a=2$ and finaly:
$$f(n)=4+6(n-1)=6n-2$$